# How can we confirm that ether was really sent using getTransactionReceipt?

Tags: go-ethereum

I send some ether in my private test system as follows -

> > eth.sendTransaction({'from':eth.coinbase, 'to':'0xfc1bdf06d1150e6eeeb229a8500b09df8ccdcbbd',
> >     'value':web3.toWei(3, 'ether')})
> >     "0x1e20e5377e0d418716a74d94a4d60090abcd9e93ad4c847be0cfa78db4477b58"
> >
> > eth.pendingTransactions []
> >
> > eth.getTransactionReceipt("0x1e20e5377e0d418716a74d94a4d60090abcd9e93ad4c847be0cfa78db4477b58")
> >     {
>
> blockHash:
>   "0xb599e7130d2b4f3b8960922781fdae0e6bcb883fca3bc0c3272b971d1b5a0322", 
>   blockNumber: 456,   contractAddress: null,   cumulativeGasUsed: 21000,
>   from: "0xfcad53c780a4f6c66b3daca331fe72fc6559c367",   gasUsed: 21000, 
>   logs: [],   logsBloom:
>   "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
>   status: "0x1",   to: "0xfc1bdf06d1150e6eeeb229a8500b09df8ccdcbbd",
>   transactionHash:
>   "0x1e20e5377e0d418716a74d94a4d60090abcd9e93ad4c847be0cfa78db4477b58", 
>   transactionIndex: 0 }

I am using Proof of Authority. I can see the sending and receiving accounts but I cannot see the actual amount sent (3eth). Is that included somewhere in the getTransactionReceipt?

Comment: If the transaction was successfully mined into a block and the block has had a number of comfirmations, you can be quite certain the ether was indeed transferred

Comment: Yes that is all fine, but I want to check so that it can be confirmed. Also in a real app, we need a dispute resolution option for cases when someone claims the money was not received. I assume it stated in the TransactionReceipt somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `getTransaction`, which returns (among other things) the `value` field of the transaction.

If the transaction receipt has `status: 1`, then the transaction was successful, and the wei in the transaction's `value` field was transferred.

Comment: That works, I just tested it. The box is too small here it copy paste the output.